# Is memory defect or is there an other possibility?

Tags: memory

I have a server running without physical access. I think there is 16Gb memory installed but I am not sure. What could be the problem here?

```
#dmidecode -t memory
# dmidecode 3.0
Scanning /dev/mem for entry point.
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0014
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK0
    Type: Other
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Manufacturer00
    Serial Number: SerNum00
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: ModulePartNumber00
    Rank: Unknown

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0014
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK1
    Type: Other
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Manufacturer01
    Serial Number: SerNum01
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: ModulePartNumber01
    Rank: Unknown
```

But then there is this:

```
# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        7881812      236436      237512        8736     7407864     7233756
```

After removing and readding the memory CentOS now uses 16Gb again:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       16139344      293560    15629068        8708      216716    15548680
```

dmidecode still says `Maximum Capacity: 8 GB`.

What irritates me is that the memory bar was always recognized but not used in the first place.

Any idea?

Comment: If `Maximum Capacity: 8 GB` means the total across the two banks then that's what you're seeing.

Comment: At first I thought you were right, but after removing and readding the memory CentOS now uses 16Gb again.

Comment: Did the `dmidecode` output change after fiddling with the sticks?

Comment: No. `dmidecode` still says `Maximum Capacity: 8 GB`.